# Как прочесть файл из игры Киберпанк со странной кодировкой?

Tags: python, кодировка

я пишу работу по синтезу речи. Я достал звуковые файлы озвучки из Киберпанка в формате wav и субтитры к ним. С звуковыми файлами все прекрасно, а вот субтитры закодированы в файле json.
При просмотре в Notepad в формате utf-8 видны реплики главных героев, а все остальные поля выглядят нечитаемыми:

[image: Так отображается json файл в Notepad]

Прочитать такой файл средствами python тоже не получается, постоянно ругается что какой-то символ не может опознать, перепробовал все кодировки.

```
with open(file="q116_05_mikoshi.json", encoding="utf_8",mode="r") as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```

Задача прочитать файл, чтоб можно было разобрать ту часть что не отображается.

Comment: Обычный бинарный файл. Но шаблон субтитров читается прекрасно. Парси...

Comment: Это `CR2W` файл от Кибарпанка (по крайней мере гугль такое выдаёт). Вроде есть утилиты, позволяющие такие файлы конвертировать в нормальные `json` и прочие "обычные" файлы. Так что сначала сконвертируйте, а потом уже читайте как `json`.

Comment: Сейчас попробую!

Comment: Занимаюсь аналогичной задачей. Вам удалось сопоставить транскрипции и аудиофайлы?
Можете поделиться скриптом?

Comment: Это json?? Серьёзно???

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решён, что потребовалось:

1. Скачать CP77 MODDING TOOLS с нексуса https://www.nexusmods.com/cyberpunk2077/mods/8?tab=description
2. Запустить его и ввести в командной строке

   WolvenKit.CLI cr2w -p "G:\WolvenKit CLI\q116_05_mikoshi2.json" -s
   где q116_05_mikoshi2.json зашифрованный JSON
3. Наслаждаться нормальным JSON форматом =)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]